# How to resolve error "unrecognized command line option '-std=c++1y'" when using mingw32-make.exe

Tags: mingw32

I've been trying to build a set of code given to me for a research project. I'm running windows 7 and the code I am working with is in c++.

I'm using the `CMake 3.5.2 GUI` to configure and generate a `makefile` for the code. I've never used `CMake` before, so I could be wrong about how I'm operating it, but I built a `Makefile` first with the generator titled "MinGW Makefiles". This seems to have worked fine after choosing `"None"` for the `"CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE"` parameter. Then, using command prompt I attempted to run `mingw32-make` while in the `"build"` directory, which is where the `Makefile` generated by `CMake` was stored.

When I tried to do this, these errors were returned in command prompt:

```
G__~1.EXE: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++1y'
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/finch-maze_gen.dir/src/maze_gen/maze_gen.cpp.obj] Error1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/finch-maze_gen.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The `mingw32-make.exe` file that I am using is in the Program Files for `CodeBlocks`. I'm pretty sure that when I downloaded `CodeBlocks` I downloaded the `MinGW` version.

I tried using the generator titled `"CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"` in `CMake` and then opening the `CodeBlocks` project created in the build folder, then building it with the `"build"` button in `CodeBlocks`. The error message in `CodeBlocks` was identical to the one given to me in command prompt.

So far, I've found [this resource](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-std-108) explaining the meaning of `'-std=c++1y'`.

Apparently it means that the language standard is being set to the 2014 version of `c++`.

As far as I can tell, Error 1 has something to do with improper spacing, or a use of spacing when there should be tabs

Does anyone know a good fix for any of the errors? 
Also, I am considering using `make.exe` instead of `mingw32-make.exe`. Does anyone have any suggestions on where to download this? Or will it even make any difference if I use that?

Comment: `The name ‘c++1y’ is deprecated`. RTM please

Comment: `Error 1` just means a generic error. What you need to do is figure out whether the code you're compiling really *needs* C++14 (in which case you must upgrade to a newer version) or whether you can get away with C++11. What exact GCC version do you have?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you are using a version of GCC older than when the name `c++1y` was coined

Comment: When the code was given to you, what were the build instructions and are you able to build it in the way specified in this instructions?

Comment: @M.M The instructions given to me were this, as far as building the code goes: _"As for building it, you'll need CMake. Create a folder called "build" in the code folder, cd to it in a terminal, and run "cmake .." and then "make""_. I was unable to build the code in this way mainly because I did not have the _make_ command available to me.

Comment: @o11c I looked into what GCC version I have. As far as I can tell, the version of GCC that I have is in the "MinGW" folder included with my download of CodeBlocks 13.12. That was downloaded in 2012. Should I uninstall that version of MinGW and download a newer version?

Comment: I'd recommend getting CB 16.01 without bundled compiler, and installing mingw-w64 from [official site](http://www.mingw-w64.org).

Comment: If `make` is unavailable try `mingw32-make`.  You may have to set up some paths.

Comment: @ProfessionalGrammer Learn go call `<program> --version` to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped! The problem is solved. I ended up downloading the newest version of mingw and "making" the project with that and it worked how I was expecting it to